# Resize dat.gui in three.js

Tags: javascript, user-interface, three.js

I'm using a dat gui in three.js.

Unfortunately my gui is very very big, and I cant't resize it. I tried with `autoplace=false`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 12):

Try setting a width in the constructor parameters along with autoPlace: false

```js
var gui = new dat.GUI( { autoPlace: false, width: 300 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following code to shrink your panel:

```
    function datgui(){
    let gui = new dat.GUI({
        width : 300
    });
```